# Understanding Einstein theory for Brownian motion.

Tags: probability

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion#Einstein's_theory) they describe Einstein theory as follows: Let $\Delta $ be the increment of a particle in time $\tau$ (it's a random variable) with density $\varphi (\Delta )$. Using Taylor at time $t+\tau$ for the density (number of particles per unit volume), we have $$\rho(x,t)+\tau\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}+\mathcal O(t^2)=\rho(x,t+\tau)\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R}\rho(x-\Delta ,t)\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta =\rho(x,t)\int_{\mathbb R}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\int_{\mathbb R}\Delta \varphi (\Delta )d\Delta +\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta +O(\Delta ^3)=\rho(x,t)+\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta +O(\Delta ^3).$$

**Q1)** Where does equality $(*)$ come from?

**Q2)** After they conclude that by setting $D=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2\tau}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta $, we get $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2},$$ It's maybe obvious but I don't understand where this comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) I think is like a continuos version of the marginal distribution of markov chains, both things are stochastic, in the discrete version you get something [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Transient_evolution)

$$ \Pr(X_{n+1}=j) = \sum_{r \in S} p_{rj} \Pr(X_n=r)$$
so your probability of being at the state $j$ at the step $n+1$ depends on the all the possible states $r$ at the previous step $n$, similarty you have that

$$\rho(x,t+\tau)\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R}\rho(x-\Delta ,t)\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta$$
so your probability of being at the postion $x$ at the time $t+\tau$ depends on all the possible position $x-\Delta$ at the previous time $t$

Q2)Look at the first and last equation you wrote, and forget about terms $\mathcal{O(\tau^2)}$, $\mathcal{O(\Delta ^3)}$
$\rho(x,t)+\tau\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}+\mathcal{O(\tau^2)}=\rho(x,t)+\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta +\mathcal{O(\Delta ^3)}$

$\rho(x,t)+\tau\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}=\rho(x,t)+\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta$

$\tau\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta$

$\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\Delta ^2}{2\tau}\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta$

$\frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2}$

Comment: Thank you for, your answer. For Q2), I agree, but why should I forget about $O(t^2)$ and $O(\Delta ^3)$. If I don't consider them, then it's not an equality anymore.

Comment: Is like if you have $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ and use their taylor series then $(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+...)^2=1-(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} +...)^2$ or $(1+\mathcal{O(x^2)})^2=1-(x+\mathcal{O(x^3))^2}$, if $x$ is far from $0$ then $\mathcal{O(x^2)},\mathcal{O(x^3)}$ will contribute to keep this equality true but if your are close they won't and so you can drop them and although cosine is not a constant function and sine is not a linear function either they´re when you're close to $0$ and the equality still will hold more or less.

Comment: Also edited the answer to change $\mathcal{O(t)}$ with $\mathcal{O(\tau)}$

Comment: Sorry, but this should be proved rigorously. I agree with what you said, but I would like to be rigorously convinced. So in $Q2)$, the second and the 3 line doesn't really look correct rigorously. Could you provide a rigorous proof of this fact ?

Comment: Notice one can't hope for a rigorous proof of this (Q2)  without asking for a rigorous definition of the relation (Q1) from which you desire to obtain your result, what exactly is $\rho(x,t+\tau)\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R}\rho(x-\Delta ,t)\varphi (\Delta )d\Delta$ after all? I answered within the context of the link you provided, I'm bound to get it wrong if I try it myself and doubt there is a treatment in that fashion of the brownian motion, but would suggest to look at wienner processes as are the the closest to this on a purely mathematical setting, hope you can find about it there